# Implication in L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: calculus

When an unknown quotient $ \dfrac{0}{0} $ is indeterminate  it is *hypothesized* as an indeterminate maximum /minimum   point, is n't it?

For, when quotient of two functions

$ \dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{0}{0} = const.,$  is considered and we apply Quotient Rule for the first indeterminate fraction by differentiating w.r.t. $t$,

$$  \dfrac {y x^{\prime} - y^{\prime}  x}{y^2} = 0,  \quad  \dfrac {x}{y} =   \dfrac {x^{\prime} }{y^{\prime} }  \tag{1} $$

is what forms the L'Hôpital's Rule *as a consequence*. Right?

Now how far is the *assumption* of the unknown to be locally constant, and not be a variable,correct?

EDIT

Apologies. An error occurred while considering multi-variable calculus context, but here makes no sense.Not deleting it as there are already some answers. Sincere apology again for attentions gone improperly, prefer to close it in its present form.

Comment: I don't think the quotient rule can be used at all. One must use the extended mean value theorem to prove the L'Hopital rule, and that does not assume that the ratio is a constant or a variable.

Comment: The moment you reach $\dfrac{0}{0}$, you need to take a step back (or many steps) and try to find a way of avoiding it.  One possibility is reframing the question as one of limits.

Comment: This question makes no sense whatsoever to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to consider the problem : assuming that functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have all required properties around $x=a$, use Taylor expansions $$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a) f'(a)+\frac{1}{2} (x-a)^2 f''(a)+\frac{1}{6} f'''(a)
   (x-a)^3+O\left((x-a)^4\right)$$ $$g(x)=g(a)+(x-a) g'(a)+\frac{1}{2} (x-a)^2 g''(a)+\frac{1}{6} g'''(a)
   (x-a)^3+O\left((x-a)^4\right)$$ and now, consider what happens to $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(a)+(x-a) f'(a)+\frac{1}{2} (x-a)^2 f''(a)+\frac{1}{6} f'''(a)
   (x-a)^3+O\left((x-a)^4\right) }{ g(a)+(x-a) g'(a)+\frac{1}{2} (x-a)^2 g''(a)+\frac{1}{6} g'''(a)
   (x-a)^3+O\left((x-a)^4\right)}$$ when $f^{(n)}(a)$ and/or $g^{(m)}(a)$ tend to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

L'Hôpital is proven more or less like this: Say you have two continuously differentiable functions $f(x), g(x)$ such that $f(a) = g(a) = 0$, $g'(a) \neq 0$ and $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists. (You can relax these constraints somewhat, specifically the "continuously differentiable" part, as well as allowing $g'(a) = 0$, if you want a more thorough proof, including the fact that repeated applications is valid. However, the basic idea is still the same.)

We have, for any $x$ where $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ makes sense, that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{g(x) - g(a)}$, since we're simply adding $0$ to both the numerator and the denominator.

But we're also allowed to divide the numerator and the denominator by any non-zero number we want. For instance, for the $x$-values for which $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ make sense, we have that $x-a$ is non-zero. So
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f(x)- f(a)}{g(x) - g(a)} = \frac{\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}}{\frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x - a}}
$$
Lastly, since the leftmost and rightmost fractions are equal wherever they make sense, any of their *limits* must be the same as well. Specifically,
$$
\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}}{\frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x - a}} = \frac{\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}}{\lim_{x \to a}\frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x - a}} = \frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}
$$

Comment: What you state at the end is *not* l'Hôpital's theorem, but just an algebraic manipulation which is possible if you *assume* the existence of the derivatives at $a$.

Comment: @egreg I am aware that it should really be $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$, and that the equality "goes the other way". But my result here is how l'Hôpital is most often used in practice when doing problems. So while it's not the true statement, it is the statement that students become familiar with.